# How to identify a downvoting stalker

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Yeah I got a deranged stalker that keeps downvoting me.

Anyone know how going about identifying such individuals?

(I just got 4 all at the same time just after making a new post).

---

[Android Fragments : Inheritance vs Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992459/android-fragments-inheritance-vs-composition)

that was the question I originally asked. Please tell me, what is so wrong with it ?

Comment: It couldn't possibly be that your question was of similar quality to this one?

Comment: Don't abuse tags. To answer your question: bring it to the attention of a moderator, let them deal with the individual in question, and ignore it.

Comment: @EricLippert: Ahm, no, not really. If I'm not completely mistaken (and policy hasn't changed) serial voting is **not** something you bother the mods with unless it's a **really, really, really** scary edge-case...but still better come to Meta about it first.

Comment: Sorry I had no Idea. Well, I just went from 204 to 180 in like 10 minutes.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Good point. I amend my comment to: **Don't abuse tags**, and, if the automatic serial downvoting detection script doesn't seem to be working, *then* post on Meta.

Comment: @SamusArin well a big part of your drop is the fact that you asked this question on SO and got 6 downvotes, that would account for most of that rep decrease.  But the other downvotes on older questions does seem a bit off... I would wait for the serial voting script and see if it better tomorrow.

Comment: I don't normally abuse, and respect this site/community and have never started anything with anyone. I got out of my way to write full questions and answers. I'm really pissed and figured this would get attention. If I knew it was such a big deal I wouldn't of. Man.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Ok, got it. I do apologize.

Comment: @TyrionLannister http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992459/android-fragments-inheritance-vs-composition this was the question, cool guy.

Comment: And now you have another downvote for your impolite remarks about downvotes at the top of the question.

Comment: @SamusArin: How is it possible that this was a "stalker?" It looks like all of the downvotes were on the same question (please correct me if I'm wrong). It's not possible for one user to downvote a question multiple times.

Comment: @David Robinson ... bc everytime I post a new question, Itll get downvoted, and almost at the same time a few of my older questions get dinged. This has happend for the last few posts.

Comment: @Rosinante impolite out of justified anger. See the comments in the questions below, where TyrionLannister agreed that my question was ok!

Comment: @SamusArin: Whoa now.  I said it met MY personal requirements, but couldn't speak for everyone else.  Please refrain from saying I said that it was "ok".

Comment: @TyrionLannister Your statment above "It couldn't possibly be that your question was of similar quality to this one" implies that I asked a horrible question. That upset me b/c I spent a lot of time asking (to make it readable). I'm not going to argue over semantics; "ok" vs "meets my personal requirments". I wasn't talking about everyone else, b/c it was you that originally made the statment.

Comment: @TyrionLannister ... I'm going to shutup now, I really don't want to piss anyone off...

Comment: @SamusArin: I really am trying to help :) but I'm looking at your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1105214/samus-arin?tab=reputation) and I truly don't see any evidence of a stalker (unless some votes were reversed). Today you received 2 downvotes 1 hour ago (3 originally I think), and you got one single downvote on a very old question. You got one unexplained downvote yesterday, and then your last downvote was way back on November 7. How is that "everytime I post a new question, Itll get downvoted, and almost at the same time a few of my older questions get dinged"?

Comment: In fact, with the exception of your most recent question, you have to go all the way back to *July* to find one of your questions that has had a single downvote. Where is the pattern you're talking about? Or did there used to be downvotes that were reversed?

Comment: @David Robinson They were thankfully reversed. My score is fixed (I didn't realize how high it was, all those downvotes were damaging. I think I have one question that was bad, but I made a note of my mistake in the post and left it). Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @SamusArin - I looked into this using the tools we have at our disposal, and I see no pattern at all to any downvotes you've received. They don't appear to be the work of an individual or any sort of proxy account, and may just be coincidental downvotes that happened around the same time. People targeting other users tend to vote in rapid bursts, not the two downvotes spaced a ways apart that you saw today.

Comment: @Brad Larson Thanks for checking... Well, I can tell you that it only happens when I post on the Android tag, and it always occurs in 2's (2 DV's). I just answered a question, complete with code example, on the android tag, and it got DV'ed even though its near identical to the other answers that got posted at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023329/how-can-i-set-a-custom-font-on-my-listview/14023400#14023400 can you please check again, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Votes are anonymous - there is no direct way to identify such individuals.

However, serial downvoting is a known problem and there are automated mechanisms to identify and correct reputation issues caused by it.

Comment: Well I figured there site ops or admins must be able to check. I just want it stopped. Its annoying, and lame, and makes me not even want to contribute. I've never started beef with anyone, and actually went out of my way to fix a few downvotes I did too quickly (havent done more than 4 or 5 ever).

Comment: @SamusArin - If it continues, the serial downvoting script will find the culprits and they will end up being banned. In any case, once the script finds an issue your reputation will be refunded.

Comment: The last few questions I've asked have gotten almost immediate downvotes with no explaination.

Comment: Thanks... I'm sure whoever it is just created a temp account, both for anonymity, and b/c downvoting without explanation takes points away, which they've been doing.

Comment: @SamusArin - That does not sound like a stalker to me. Did you consider that the posts were not very good?

Comment: @SamusArin: You can't downvote unless you've got 125 rep.  And downvoting a question never takes away rep.  Downvoting an answer, with comment or not, will take a minor rep hit.

Comment: @Oded Everytime I post, that question will get downvoted, and at the same time (almost) a few other, random, old posts will get downvoted as well. This has been the trend. I think unexplained downvotes are for people that don't fully understand the question, or are just plain aholes.

Comment: @TyrionLannister http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992459/android-fragments-inheritance-vs-composition thats the question I asked, you tell me the quality of it.

Comment: @SamusArin: I know.  I read the update to your question, plus the other comment you wrote @ me.  The comment I made here was in reply to you're "they created a temp account" comment.

Comment: @TyrionLannister downvoting with no explanation is so productive, and has the fantastic side effect of serial downvoting. Such a great idea, and so beneficial to the community as a whole. Not sure how many more posts I'll be making, or questions I'll be answering.

Comment: @SamusArin: People here like their anonymity.  And many feel that they shouldn't have to give a reason for the downvotes, which is true.  Often times, I'll see it and realize why all on my own.  There are LOADS of questions here on Meta about that very issue.  All that being said, looking at your question, it meets my personal requirements of sample code, what you've tried, and your issue.  Though I can't speak for others.

Comment: @TyrionLannister To be honest, I think its because I added the code first, and even though I had a quick sentence saying the description was below, I think people that answer a lot glanced an were like, only code!, ding. I wasn't even going to put code in, but I find those questions dont get answered. So, I reorganized, and added a summary in bold (as prolink007 pointed out). I defly got a stalker though (because I explain my downvotes!).

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago and i just submitted a ticket about it and it was resolved within minutes. Try emailing support and letting them know. Or flag a question that you have asked on the SE and put in the flag what is going on and that will usually get someone to help you as well.

Comment: I quote from the question which this was closed as duplicate of: "What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud? ... Please do not try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator."

Comment: Well it worked in my situation.

Comment: I've never had this problem before. Now that I posted a link here to the original question I asked today, its getting even more downvotes, with no explainations.

Comment: @SamusArin: your question clearly states you would like to identify the parties involved in voting. Voting is anonymous and many feel very strongly about it. Votes on Meta work differently. Moreover, posting to the wrong site and not searching meta for questions which already apply typically will get you *at least* 3-5 downvotes. (Regardless, reputation on meta means nothing)

Comment: @sixlettervariables Hey man, I remember you... I really had no idea that Meta-SO was the place for this, or even existed. I must admit I let anger get the best of me and made a post with tags that had many users (and that I use often) to get recognition. If I new how ticked off it would make everyone, I definitely wouldn't have done this.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - That's only referring to the 24 hours before the automated script runs. If the script doesn't handle this voting, it is perfectly fine to flag for a moderator's attention, as long as we're talking about more than 3 or 4 votes here. We also like to know if someone is targeting somebody else, because we can warn people in the more extreme cases or even provide a suspension if this is part of a pattern of bad behavior.